# Тип функции, возвращающей три различные сущности.

Tags: архитектура, java

Имеется класс-коллекция с методом `get`, который в зависимости от переданных параметров может вернуть экземпляр одного из трёх классов. Между классами общего лишь то, что все они могут лежать в этой коллекции.

Как с точки зрения архитектуры лучше решить эту проблему?

1. Унаследовать все три класса от одного абстрактного, чтобы пользователь сам проверял тип и кастил.
2. Сделать как в `StreamTokenizer`: завести `Enum` с тремя значениями, и функцию `getType()`, возвращающую этот `Enum`. Пользователь вызывает `getType` и в зависимости от результата получает значение с помощью одной из трёх функций `getLast*TypeName*`.
3. Свой вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 2 точно не айс - это в стиле С, но не в стиле Java

Я бы сделал вариант с интерфейсами, завел бы общий интерфейс, возможно иерархию интерфейсов. Интерфейс как более высокий уровень абстракции дает больше свободы.

**P.S.** Кстати можно чтобы в интерфейсе была функция типа `getType()`, которая будет возвращает нужный `Enum`, тогда это будет попутно реализовывать вариант №2

Answer (score 0):

если каждый класс реализует различные интерфейсы, то логичнее всего было бы запихнуть всё в Collection<Object> и доставая проверять на тип класса (instanceof). Если нужно типизировать коллекцию (ну не хотите вы чтобы туда попали ненужные классы) - заимплиментить один общий интерфейс(наследоваться можно только от одного класса, а имплименить интерфейсы - много). Это подходит если классы вообще разные по своей структуре, имеют различные методы или назначения.

Answer (score 0):

можно было бы использовать в качестве типа для коллекции просто Object, но я солидарен с [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) на счет иерархии интерфейсов:

```
interface Base {} // будет использоватся в качестве типа для коллекции
interface A extends Base {} // конкретный тип 1, должен имплементироватся класом 1
interface B extends Base {} // конкретный тип 2, ...
interface C extends Base {} // конкретный тип 3, ...
```

после получения элемента с коллекции вы спокойно можете приводить его к нужному типу:

```
if (item instanceOf A) { return (A) item; } // для типа 1, для остальных аналогично
```

p.s. интерфейсы обычно нужны для того чтоб задать что-то общее между несколькими разными классами, - зделать общий "способ" использования разных реализаций. вы же привязываетесь к конкретным реализациям. я бы посоветовал обрисовать вашу задачу детальнее, может вы допустили ошибку при проэктировании и все таки есть возможность прибегнуть к общему интерфейсу